# Как исправить ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Версия интерпретатора: 3.6.1. Вот код:

сервер:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
       break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

клиент:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send("hello, world!".encode())

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gleb/PycharmProjects/sc/kek.py", line 7, in <module>
data = sock.recv(1024)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал 
существующее подключение
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Вот так попробуйте*

```
import socket

conn = socket.socket()
conn.bind( ('localhost', 9090) )
conn.listen(100)

while True:
    try: client, addr = conn.accept()
    except socket.error: 
        pass 
    else: 

        data = client.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        client.send(data.upper())
```

Ваш исправленный код

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
client, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = client.recv(1024).decode()

    if not data:
       break
    print(data)
    client.send(data.upper().encode())

client.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по по [этому топику](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1060070/ConnectionResetError-WinError-An-existing-connecti) вы пытаетесь открыть более одного клиентского соединения, что провоцирует данную ошибку